# Vim: How to delete repetition in a line

Tags: regex, vim

I am having a log file for analysis, in that few of the line will have repetition of it own, but not complete repetition, say

```
Alex is here and Alex is here and we went out
We bothWe both went out
```

I want to remove the first occurrence and get

```
Alex is here and we went out
We both went out
```

Please share a regex to do in Vim in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend trying to use regex magic to solve this problem.  Just write an external filter and use that.

Here's an external filter written in Python.  You can use this to pre-process the log file, like so:

```
python prefix_chop.py logfile.txt > chopped.txt
```

But it also works by standard input:

```
cat logfile.txt | prefix_chop.py > chopped.txt
```

This means you can use it in vim with the `!` command.  Try these commands: goto line 1, then pipe from current line through the last line through the external program `prefix_chop.py`:

```
1G
!Gprefix_chop.py<Enter>
```

Or you can do it from ex mode:

```
:1,$!prefix_chop.py<Enter>
```

Here's the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
infile = sys.stdin if len(sys.argv) < 2 else open(sys.argv[1])

def repeated_prefix_chop(line):
    """
    Check line for a repeated prefix string.  If one is found,
    return the line with that string removed, else return the
    line unchanged.
    """
    # Repeated string cannot be more than half of the line.
    # So, start looking at mid-point of the line.
    i = len(line) // 2 + 1

    while True:
        # Look for longest prefix that is found in the string after pos 0.
        # The prefix starts at pos 0 and always matches itself, of course.
        pos = line.rfind(line[:i])
        if pos > 0:
            return line[pos:]
        i -= 1

        # Stop testing before we hit a length-1 prefix, in case a line
        # happens to start with a word like "oops" or a number like "77".
        if i < 2:
            return line

for line in infile:
    sys.stdout.write(repeated_prefix_chop(line))
```

I put a `#!` comment on the first line, so this will work as a stand-alone program on Linux, Mac OS X, or on Windows if you are using Cygwin.  If you are just using Windows without Cygwin, you might need to make a batch file to run this, or just type the whole command `python prefix_chop.py`.  If you make a macro to run this you don't have to do the typing yourself.

EDIT: This program is pretty simple.  Maybe it could be done in "vimscript" and run purely inside vim.  But the external filter program can be used outside of vim... you can set things up so that the log file is run through the filter once per day every day, if you like.

Comment: Hi, your solution worked, there is a corner case where a subset of a line matches itself, but it is not required to be chopped. I modified the if condition to `code`if pos > 0 and line.rfind(line[:pos-1]):`code` to make sure the complete line presence instead of a subset (I forget to mention that although)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.  The corner case you found is an example of why I was hesitant to try this as a pure regexp solution... this is the sort of problem that benefits from a program of some sort so you can tune it until the corner cases work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:`\b(.*)\1\b`

Replace with:`\1` or `$1`

If you want to deal with more than two repeating sentences you can try this

```
\b(.+?\b)\1+\b
      --
       |->avoids matching individual characters in word like xxx
```

---

**NOTE**

Use `\<` and `\>` instead of `\b`

Comment: +1  though not vim regex, but the idea works. (the question tagged with regex too)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by matching as much as possible at the beginning of the line and then using a backreference to match the repeated bit.

For example, this command solves the problem you describe:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)\(\1.*\)/\2
```

Comment: I came up with similar. but your command works only for repeat once. e.g. the example in OP's question. you could do something like `%s/\v(.*)\1+(.*)/\1\2/` but due to the greedy rule, this only works for repetition with even number of times . for example `ab ab ab ab xxx` (repeat 3 times) won't work. because the longest pattern would be `ab ab`.

Comment: @Kent you were close..make `.*` to `.+?` and it would work for even number of repeats..i.e `\b(.+?)\1+\b` and replace it with `$1`

Comment: also `.*` would also replace `l` in hello..you should use `\b` after it

Comment: @Anirudh No, I'm already anchoring on beginning-of-line `^`. Also, we're talking about Vim regexps here, so you need to use `\<` and `\>` instead of `\b`.

Comment: @Anirudh your regex seems working!  the `.+?` is not vim regex style either. however man can do perldo to use perl regex. point is the idea. nice. I didn't think of the `\b`

Comment: Hi, the solution did not worked since it requires a word boundary to compare, but the case can be without word boundary

Comment: @SetV I think you're commenting on the wrong answer. My solution doesn't make any reference to word boundaries at all. It works just fine.

Comment: @glts How to avoid sub repetition in a repetition, say when there is a  bigger string repeated with some repetition in it. Also a line might not have any string repetition but might have few continuous char match. Is it possible to address in regexp?